# Calling async function Subscription from a component ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

getting data from my service, does not wait for the service to finish.

Below is Component to get data for my grid, the problem is this part this.store.loadRequestHistory(this.id),when hover on store no data from items.

```
export class HistoryGridComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;

 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
             private router: Router, 
             public store: HistoryStore) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.paramMap
          .map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('id'))
          .subscribe(id => {
              this.id = parseInt(id, 10);
              let list =  this.store.loadRequestHistory(this.id); // I need my data here 
          });
  }
```

Below is my method from a service/store. this gets the data fine with no issues.

```
 @action public async loadRequestHistory(requestId: number): Subscription {
        this.loading = true;
        let history = new HistoryClient(this.http, environment.apiUrl);
        let response = history.getRequestHistory(requestId);
        return response.subscribe(
            (data) => {
                try {
                    this.items = _(data)
                        .map(historySummaryMapper.map)
                        .value();

                    this.itemCount = data.length;

                    this.loading = false;
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                }


            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.loading = false;
            },
            () => {
                 this.loading = false;
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of the view?

Comment: `async` doesn't work with observables and would require `await` anyway. Maybe you want `toPromise`?

Comment: FWIW, this is what route resolvers are for, they support both promises and observables.

Answer (score 0):

try this , make use of async/await and return observable

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.route.paramMap
          .map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('id'))
          .subscribe(async id => {
              this.id = parseInt(id, 10);

        let list=  await this.store.loadRequestHistory(this.id).toPromise();// I need my data here 

          });
  }


 public loadRequestHistory(requestId: number): Observable<any> {
        this.loading = true;
        let history = new HistoryClient(this.http, environment.apiUrl);
        let response = history.getRequestHistory(requestId);
        return response;
   }
```

Comment: It will expectedly throw an error. await is in regular function. loadRequestHistory(this.id) doesn't have toPromise.

Comment: @estus - thats why i chaged loadRequestHistory method also which retuns overservable

Comment: subscribe(async id ...) is antipattern. I'm quite sure that throwing away all logic inside response.subscribe() won't work as intended. There should be .do() or else.

Comment: @estus - yes its true , but i am trying to suggest way how to achieve it , and yes `of(data)` can create observable if dont have to throw code in that big service method

Comment: yeah even though its an observable it throws "this.store.loadRequestHistory(...).toPromise is not a function" and toPromise() is imported

Comment: @AneleNgqandu - not getting you , is that worked or you are facing issue >

Comment: @PranayRana no its complaining

Comment: ow ok its working, the items from the store suppose to be IObservableArray